# confusion in complexity of this algo

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

```
DAA(n)
{
    if(n<=1)
    {
         return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return(DAA(n/2)+DAA(n/2)+n);
    }
}
```

I am confused in the return statement having term n. whether it will be calculated as `T(n)=2T(n/2)+n`; or `T(n)=2T(n/2)+c`, and please explain why?

Comment: For `n==1` , it is `T(1)=1` , for `n` , it is `T(n)=2T(n/2)+c` !

Comment: this DAA is the function which complexity is in question, or it models the work that been done by some function?

Answer (score 1):

It will be the latter, because the trailing `n` is not in a function call (in order for it to be the former it would need to be something like `return(DAA(n/2)+DAA(n/2)+DAA(n-1));`

Answer (score 0):

Computing addition of any number is usually considered constant time. Therefore

```
T(n) = 2T(N/2) + 2*time_to_compute_a_addition
```

That is

```
T(C) = 2T(N/2)+c
```

Comment: thanks hivert....
sorry but one more problem I have...
what if return ( n * DAA(n^1/2) ); 
its under root n(n power 1/2).